# How to enable scrolling when adjusting height of browser on a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So i created a **flexbox** like as follow and coloured the border as shown:

[image]

and basically what I'm trying to do now is to only let the box **flex width wise** whenever i **resize** the **browser window** which is working by default:

[image]

However, what I want now is that I **only want it to flex whenever the width of the browser window** is **adjusted** but **not when the height of the browser window is adjusted**. If i adjust the browser height now, the flexbox responds as such:

[image]

Therefore what I **want** is, whenever the **height of the browser is reduced**, i want the flexbox **height** to remain **unchanged** and make it **scrollable height wise** hence the **scrollbar** at the side would **show** whenever the **height** is **reduced**. It's similar to the https://www.apple.com/ website where if we adjust the width of the browser, it flexes but height wise its utilizing the scrollbar.

How do i achieve this?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "outer">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer solved your problem or was useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore what I want is, whenever the height of the browser is reduced, i want the flexbox height to remain unchanged and make it scrollable height wise hence the scrollbar at the side would show whenever the height is reduced.

Given this requirement, what I would do is

1. Remove the `height: 90%;` line in your CSS. This is causing your flexbox to take up 90% of the height of your browser window, even upon resizing.
2. Add `flex-direction: column;`
3. Add some content that takes up more height than your browser window. You mentioned [www.apple.com](https://www.apple.com/), after all :-)
4. Watch the vertical scrollbar appear!

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id = "outer">
    <p>Images and text and content, oh my!</p>
    <p>Images and text and content, oh my!</p>
    <p>Images and text and content, oh my!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
}

p {
    font-size: x-large;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 300px; /* or other sufficiently large property:value */
}
```